# Pipeline from <filename> to <filename> in Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, redirection, pipe

Is there a way to do this without a temporary file?

I've tried with [`tee`](https://code.google.com/p/wintee) but that failed.

Test case:

```
>echo "foo bar" > ex2.go

>type ex2.go
"foo bar"


>type ex2.go > ex2.go

>type ex2.go
```

---

Specific problem is with Go:

```
G:\gocode\vimeo-examples>gofmt.exe ex2.go > ex2.go
ex2.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
```

On its own, [`gofmt`](http://gofmt.com) ([docs](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt)) does a code format and outputs to stdout. I'd rather it format the code in place, like `astyle` does.

Comment: When you direct output to the same file with `>`, it *first* clears the output file. If you use `>>` it'll maintain the existing contents, and append the output (which is not what you want). Basically, you need to use a temporary file if you want to use `>`.  Why not just make a batch file that  launches GoFmt, and then cleans the temporary file for you?

Comment: Is there no alternative? - I was thinking about `tee`...

Comment: I'm sure there's plenty of alternative ways to do it, and you may even be able to use a form of text redirection if you find the right tool(s).  I'm just not sure why you're so opposed to a temporary file? You're considering using 3rd party utilities, which seems like way more of a resource hog than a simple batch + temporary text file would be.  To me anyway.  Anyhow good luck!